# jQuery off() not working with an events-map

Tags: jquery, events, binding, dictionary

I'm trying to use the events-map property in `jQuery.off()` to disable events, but it doesn't seem to disable the events.

According to the jQuery docs `off()` should use the keys of the events-map and ignore the values.

Here's an example:
http://jsfiddle.net/tNBMM/

Checking the checkbox should do a simple hover effect. Unchecking it calls the `off()` function, which (as I see it) should disable the events, but doesn't.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`off()` requires the exact same function reference that was used with `on()` in order to disable it.  In your current version, you're technically creating new `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` handlers each time the checkbox is clicked.  Here's an updated version that uses the same function reference for `on()` and `off()`, working as expected: http://jsfiddle.net/tNBMM/2/

---

Edit: For the sake of any future visitors, here's the working code:

```
var enter = function() { $('#thing').css('background-color', 'red'); },
    leave = function() { $('#thing').css('background-color', 'white'); };
$('#show').click( function() {
    var show = $(this).is(':checked');

    $('#thing')[show ? 'on' : 'off']({
        mouseenter: enter,
        mouseleave: leave
    });
});​
```

Comment: the fiddle isn't working for me, the hover effect is still there after I uncheck the checkbox. :s

Comment: Doh - I had the right explanation, but botched the implementation :). Try the updated link (code example also updated).

Comment: The key is moving the `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` handler definitions outside of the `click` handler - that way the same function references are used in both `on()` and `off()`. I was just dumb and didn't move them "far enough" :)

Comment: A little implementation with $(this) in functions — [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/shehovn/tNBMM/3/)

Comment: Works perfect and with a solid explanation. Thank you!